# Multiple Authentication "OR" not working in Google Cloud Endpoints OpenAPI

Tags: swagger, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi

In Google Cloud Endpoints, I am unable to have authentication occur in an "or" scenario, where, for example, I want to allow access to a path by means of an api_key "or" oauth.  Please see https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/ for more info.

DOES WORK (single defintion for API key)

```
/api/query:
  get:
  operationId: queryget
  responses:
    '200':
      description: query success
  security:
     - api_key: []
```

DOES WORK (single definition for oauth)

```
/api/query:
  get:
  operationId: queryget
  responses:
    '200':
      description: query success
  security:
     - oauth: []
```

DOES WORK ("AND" definition where both must be included in auth)

```
/api/query:
  get:
  operationId: queryget
  responses:
    '200':
      description: query success
  security:
     - oauth: []
       api_key: []
```

DOES NOT WORK ("OR" definition)

```
/api/query:
  get:
  operationId: queryget
  responses:
    '200':
      description: query success
  security:
     - oauth: []
     - api_key: []
```

To be more specific when deploying my api to Google Cloud Endpoints, I receive the following warning

```
Operation 'get' in path '/api/query': Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project.
```

And, when trying to call the api with an API key, I receive the following error, as if it were expecting the OAUTH JWT token (maybe because it was the first security definition in the list for that route)

```
{ "code": 16, "message": "JWT validation failed: Missing or invalid credentials", "details": [  {   "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",   "stackEntries": [],   "detail": "auth"  } ]}'
```

Comment: You need to be more precise about what "does not work" means. What are the symptoms? The error you mention is only a warning.

Comment: I updated the description to include the error message.  Please let me know if you would like further info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is unsupported, unfortunately. You can only use AND. This is now documented in [Unsupported OpenAPI Features](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-limitations).

Comment: would be a great feature request going forward. Thanks for the quick response.